# In this JS code, how to add permanent arrows in each frame the box moves to show a tracking path?

Tags: javascript, html

In this javascript code, I am finding it hard to add permanent arrows to the moving box to indicate it's line path. How to add arrows to track it's path using pure javascript?

I created a box of 50x50 pixel which moves diagonally from top left to bottom right and vice versa . But each time the box moves, I want to add permanent arrows for tracking the path it goes, just like from this screenshot - https://ibb.co/7GrqxW1 I used setTimeout() to make the box move y-axis first and then x-axis as per my homework instruction. Now how to add the arrows to draw a tracking path similar to the screenshot that I have attached?

**HTML Code:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
</head>

<body class="body">
    <div id="box">
    </div>
    <script src="animate.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:-**

```
.body {
    border: 1px solid none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**JS:-**

```js
let box = document.getElementById("box");
let direction = 1;

box.style.left = "0px";
box.style.top = "0px";


function startBox() {
    let pLeft = parseInt(box.style.left);
    let pTop = parseInt(box.style.top);


    box.style.top = (pTop + 32 * direction) + "px";

    setTimeout(() => {
        box.style.left = (pLeft + 61 * direction) + "px";

    }, 150)


    if (pLeft >= window.innerWidth - 150 && pTop >= window.innerHeight - 197) {
        direction = -1;


    } else if (pLeft <= 0 && pTop <= 0) {
        direction = 1;
    }

}

setInterval(startBox, 650);
```

At first, arrows should be created dynamically but the question is how to set them. How to set the arrows like in the screenshot attached above? So that each time the box moves horizontally or vertically, the arrows will pop up and mark the path of the box.

It would be helpful if someone showed the demo.

Comment: Let's look at it like this. What are the arrows, in the context of your DOM? They should be additional elements, right? Since they don't exist on pageload, you would have to create them dynamically, every time your box moves. You would also need to register the general vertical and horizontal direction (new box coordinates versus the old ones), in order to know what the arrow rotation should be (top to bottom, left to right, bottom to top, right to left, or, perhaps, even diagonally). Or you can simplify it, and render / create the arrows once one coordinate changes.

Comment: Yes, tried to create them dynamically and also append them when each time the box moved, but the problem is the arrows are getting added only at the top of the page, not in the position that I want, tried them with 'style.left/top' setting to px values but somewhere I am missing something for sure, maybe have to set the position types but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Your arrows would have to have the `position: absolute`, and their parent element `position: relative`. Then, when you set the `top` and `left` values for a specific arrow, it should work.

Comment: Okay I tried this and it works almost, just have to adjust the alignments.
Code sample - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gHQW-toKrq1_nngxQmUk-mNkBQv8Ic5YidwZ_NH8t7E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: final update: https://helpful-caramel-b6f159.netlify.app/

Comment: Seems to be working correctly.